# cluster standard errors with small group sizes but large number of groups

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, clustered-standard-errors

I have tried looking for cluster standard errors and the only reference that I found are that problems will arise if the group is small but group size is large.

However, in the case when group size is small (<10) but the number of groups are large, will there be a problem also?

Moreover, is the problem affected by the number of independent regressors also?
(For instance having more regressors than the group sizes in some group)

The group sizes also not fixed between groups also.

Thank you!

Comment: When the number of groups is large and each group has small size, you have to use the cluster-robust variance if you are going to estimate the regression with pooled OLS. The cluster-robust variance remains valid even when the group sizes vary and the number of explanatory variables exceed the group size.